# How to write the SQL query - Where and Orderby

Tags: sql

The problem statement is
DESCRIPTION:
Display bank employee designation, id, name and gender of those employees who have a manager id, sorted in descending order of designation and ascending order of employee name.

Sample Output:

[image]

The E-R Diagram

[image]

I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT DESIGNATION, BANK_EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_SEX
FROM BANK_EMPLOYEE
WHERE MANAGER_ID IN (MANAGER_ID) AND
ORDER BY EMP_NAME, DESIGNATION DESC
```

Output: Empty

Comment: it's not even supposed to execute, the syntax is wrong

Comment: the where clause is incorrect, you may want where not manager_id is null, but its hard to tell from your question

Comment: We don't know what type of values are in `MANAGER_ID`, but assuming it's an int, valid WHERE clauses would be things like `WHERE MANAGER_ID IN (1, 2, 4)` (set of known values) `WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL` (speaks by itself), it can also be a dynamic selection `WHERE MANAGER_ID IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)`, but it cannot be a column name

Comment: The `AND` after the where statement should not be there either

Comment: Can someone write the correct  SQL statement?

Comment: Re "Can someone write the correct SQL statement?" - you can. You have got multiple hints, what is wrong and what is needed, further work is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DESIGNATION, BANK_EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_SEX
FROM BANK_EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY EMP_NAME, DESIGNATION DESC
```

That would be my first attempt, but I don't have a lot of time right now to really look into your question. If you do want, as suggested, every record where manager ID is not null, try this:

```
SELECT 
DESIGNATION, BANK_EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_SEX
FROM BANK_EMPLOYEE
WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY EMP_NAME, DESIGNATION DESC
```

If that is not correct, I can have another look for you when I have some more time.

Comment: I tried both queries but it's not working!